# Scalate console and unfiltered?

Tags: scala, scalate, unfiltered

I found [scalate-console](http://scalate.fusesource.org/documentation/console.html) on the Scalate website.  I think it would help significantly with debugging.  Is there a way to use scalate-console with unfiltered?  The site says that it uses "WAR overlay" to integrate the feature.  Should it also work with `mvn jetty:run`?